# java 8 stream - how to get original object reference after map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is at all possible to simply the below code using Java 8 stream?

Code:-

```
private double calculateBCMMatrixCostForAnalyte(Long startingMaterialId) {

    double bcmMatrixCost = 0;

    StartingMaterialMatrix smm = startingMaterialMatrixRepository.findByStartingMaterialId(startingMaterialId);

    if (smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() != null) {
        bcmMatrixCost += (priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(smm.getBlending1Matrix().getId()) * smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration()) / 1000000f;
    }

    if (smm.getBlending2MatrixConcentration() != null) {
        bcmMatrixCost += (priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(smm.getBlending2Matrix().getId() * smm.getBlending2MatrixConcentration())) / 1000000f;
    }

    return Precision.round(bcmMatrixCost, 4);
}
```

I tried something like below

```
    Stream.of(startingMaterialMatrixRepository.findByStartingMaterialId(startingMaterialId))
            .filter(smm -> smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() != null)
            .mapToDouble(smm ->  priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(smm.getStartingMaterial().getId()) * smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() / 1000000f);
```

But after this, I won't have any reference to the original 'smm' object to do further checks.

Comment: There is no point in converting anything to use streams just because you've got them now - you either get nothing at all from it, or even worse performance to boot. Original code is perfectly reasonable and only needs a minor refactoring to maybe extract common patterns into a separate method.

Comment: When you want to simplify the code, use local variables instead of repeating expressions like `getBlending2MatrixConcentration()`. Further, divide the resulting sum by `1000000` instead of each summand. Converting the processing of a single element to a stream processing doesn’t simplify the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is really not readable, but here it is

```
public double streamWay(Long startingMaterialId) {

    return Stream.of(startingMaterialMatrixRepository.findByStartingMaterialId(startingMaterialId))
            .map(Stream::of)
            .flatMapToDouble(smmStream ->
                    DoubleStream.concat(
                            smmStream.filter(smm -> smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() != null)
                                    .mapToDouble(smm -> priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(smm.getStartingMaterial().getId()) * smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() / 1000000f),
                            smmStream.filter(smm -> smm.getBlending1MatrixConcentration() != null)
                                    .mapToDouble(smm -> priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(smm.getBlending1Matrix().getId() * smm.getBlending2MatrixConcentration()) / 1000000f)
                    )).sum();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I honestly would not be hell-bent on turning this into a stream, it doesn't really need to be.

If it's overly complex to turn something into a stream, it may not be worth it, is there a specific reason?

that being said, you could make two streams, filter one, one way, then filter the other way, then use `Stream.concat` to combine the two streams, and call `.sum` but I do not think it'd be worth it.

edit:

You may need `DoubleStream.concat`, since you are mapping to double.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#concat-java.util.stream.DoubleStream-java.util.stream.DoubleStream-

Comment: It's definitely not worth it to initialize a stream pipeline just to multiply and sum couple of `double`s, especially since number of said `double`s is known upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of Stream would be good if you change your `StartingMaterialMatrix` class.
Instead of have `Blending1Matrix` and `Blending2Matrix` you should have collection `List<BlendingMatrix>` or `Set` and `BlendingMatrix` should have `concentration` and `id`
And then it will looks like this:

```
smm.getBlendingMatrixes()
.stream()
.filter(blendingMatrix -> blendingMatrix.getConcentration() != null)
.mapToDouble(blendingMatrix -> (priceService.findNeatMaterialCostByStartingMaterialId(blendingMatrix .getId()) * blendingMatrix.getConcentration())) / 1000000f)
.sum();
```